# Entity Framework Code First Soft Delete Lazy Loading

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, ef-code-first, fluent, soft-delete

So I'm using Entity Framework Code First (so no .edmx) 
I have a base entity class with a bool IsEnabled to do soft delete's

I am using repository pattern so all queries against the repository can be filtered out with IsEnabled.

However any time I use the repository to get an MyType which is IsEnabled, Lazy Loading MyType.Items may mean that Items could be not enabled.

Is there a way, perhaps with EF Fluent to describe how to do filtering on tables?

Update:

If I have a Dbset

```
public class UnitOfWork : DbContext
    {
private IDbSet<MyObj> _MyObj;
public IDbSet<MyObj> MyObjs
        {
            get { return _MyObj ?? (_MyObj = base.Set<MyObj>()); }
        }
}
```

Is there any way I can tell the DbContext to filter the DbSet?

Comment: Also after Update the answer is still: No. Of course you could add a property to the context class like `IQueryable<MyObj> MyFilteredObjs { get { return MyObjs.Where(m => m.IsEnabled); } }`. But I think that's not what you want and it doesn't get applied to lazy or eager loading.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no way to define a filter for lazy loading (also not for eager loading using `Include`). If you want that your navigation collections only get populated with items where `IsEnabled` is `true` you can only shape your queries accordingly, for example with explicit loading:

```
context.Entry(parent).Collection(p => p.Items).Query()
    .Where(i => i.IsEnabled)
    .Load();
```

This will populate the `Items` collection of `parent` only with the enabled items.

**Edit**

I feel a bit like the messenger of the bad news about a lost battle who gets his head knocked off. Maybe it's too hard to believe that Entity Framework sometimes does not have the capabilities you want. To improve my chance to convince you I add a [quote from an authority, Julie Lerman](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg309181.aspx):

> **Neither eager loading nor deferred/lazy loading in the Entity
>   Framework allows you to filter or sort the related data being
>   returned.**

Comment: It's a shame I wish there was a way to recommend it to the EF team though.

Comment: @maxfridbe: You can actually propose a feature request here: http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-ado-net-entity-framework-ef-feature-suggestions I've seen there is already a request to allow filtering with `Include` (eager loading) (place 8 in the request list), but I didn't see such a request for lazy loading.

Comment: Hi, feeling like I'm here late in the day and the solution given is a good clean one, however. What's wrong with something like this. var parent.items = context.Items.Where(x => x.parent_id == parent.parentID && x.IsEnabled == true).ToList();  So I'm using the parentID and I'm setting out the items I want.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is still possible. If you are intrested you can take a look at the [Wiktor Zychla blogpost](http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2013/10/soft-delete-pattern-for-entity.html), where he gives a solution to the soft delete problem.

Answer (score 0):

This http://blogs.claritycon.com/blog/2012/01/25/a-smarter-infrastructure-automatically-filtering-an-ef-4-1-dbset/ basically defines how I can achieve what I was looking for.

Basically you create a FilteredDbSet and make all your DbContext IDbSet's return it.

Comment: This is not an answer to your own question. This FilteredDbSet has no effect on lazy loading but only on queries for the parent entities. You have asked how you could apply a filter to the items being lazily loaded. Regarding *this* question I consider my answer (which I've edited now) still as valid.

Comment: FilteredDbSet get's me half way.  I hate to say this but I also added dogged collection to my dmain such as [NotMapped]ActiveMyObjs {return MyObjs.Where...
No way to enforce usage but does work.