# logical deletion/soft deletion in entity framework asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

Any one please provide a sample for logical or soft deletion in data base in user data table .so the data related to deleted user and all related information can be fetch later using query .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Many many duplicates, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591285/entity-framework-code-first-soft-delete-lazy-loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add flag to the user e.g. IsDeleted. Then when you delete the user you'll set flag to true.

```
class User
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    // more user properties

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

Query not-deleted users:

```
var users = DatabaseContext.Users.Where(u => !u.isDeleted );
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to your table `'IsDeleted'` column, type of BIT. Assume that you have table 'Student', you can mark student which you want to delete, just updating 'IsDeleted' column to 1. 
And you can filter when you want get data:

> SELECT * FROM Student JOIN .... WHERE IsDeleted = 0

Comment: Yes , i know use IsDelete and i am also using this but after that problem in data fetching using query because IsDeleted takes boolean value 0 and 1, but if any olumn can contain null value then problem in handle this condition.

Comment: Then don't make it nullable.